# Extracting an unique identifier from a PC using PHP without PECL?

Tags: php, security

I need to distribute a PHP site and want to control the installation To do this, I extract a unique identifier based on the hardware of the machine where the site is deployed and send that identifier to another site for validation.

How do I extract the unique identifier without using the Win32 API PECL extension?
Can someone forward me to any guides or tutorials that show how this is done?

Comment: Sory for my bad english (from Google ;) )

Comment: Dario, I believe that your question is about deploying or installing a PHP website? And you want a unique identifier for the server? If you can translate your question to English, I believe that you might get a better answer from the website ServerFault.com. That website is similar to this one -- ask questions and get answers. But here, we are talking about programming, and there, they are talking about server administration and similar topics.

Comment: i want a unique identifier for the server
Sorry for my bad english

Comment: Whats keeping the attacker from removing this check?  (nothing,  and nothing can keep him from removing it. )

Comment: Example: I get the hard drive serial, and some more serial, with this I think an ID, I send the ID with the product serial, to the web server, I associate the product serial with the ID, each X time I check this pair.
How can you violate that?

Answer (score 2):

If you are planning on limiting where your app can be installed, you will have to encode it using something like [Zend Guard](http://www.zend.com/en/products/guard/). Otherwise, no matter what restrictions you put in place, 
 they can be easily removed.

Heck, even having it encoded won't stop a determined user from getting to your source code.

Comment: ok, I turn to bytecode with Zend, but besides that, I need to extract data from the hardware to generate a unique identifier server

Comment: @Dario so if your client changes the hardware somehow, the code is going to break? Uh-oh

Comment: Ok, perfect!
I should get the server MAC with $ _SERVER ["HTTP_HOST"]
How to extract the MAC address with PHP?
PHP does not have a sentence to get the MAC address
Thank you very much.

Comment: Well... y create a function...


 function extraerMAC()
 {
 $MACexiste = false;

 $cadmac = `ipconfig /all`;
 echo $cadmac . "<br><br>";

 $macseparada = split("\n",$cadmac);

 foreach ($macseparada as $valor)
 {
 $valorSeparado = split(":",$valor);
 foreach ($valorSeparado as $linea)
 {
 if ($MACexiste)
 {
 echo "MAC : " . $linea . "<br>";
 return true;
 }
 if (trim($linea) == "Dirección física. . . . . . . . .")
 $MACexiste = true;
 }
 }
 echo "<br><br>";
 }

 extraerMAC();

now I need to replace "Dirección física" by its English translation provided by ipconfig

Thank you very much.

Answer (score 1):

By extracting hardware information, you're necessarily rendering your 'identification' script hardware-specific. PHP's a bit too high level to provide such functions (e.g., you couldn't write a device driver in PHP, as the necessary software hooks aren't there).

The methods of getting physical fingerprints are going to be different for every OS and even hardware. A device present on an x86 PC might be named something else (or completely absent) on a PowerPC Mac). On Linux, you could use various bits from /proc, on Windows, you could try replicating the fingerprinting used by Microsoft for the Windows Activation, etc...

Basically you're opening a huge can of worms which was never closed too well to start with. It's software. If someone wants to steal your code, they can and will. Your protections have to be perfect for all eternity, they just need to find one hole to get everything.

Comment: PHP code will run on windows and sometimes on linux (/proc/). Linux is a simple task, but Windows is complicated me.

Answer (score 1):

NuShere's [NuCoder](http://www.nucoder.com) allows you to encode and protect your PHP files with various options. One of those options is a unique hardware identifier it can generate for a system.

SourceGuardian is another tool that allows for good protection and is constantly updated. However, they only allow binding to license files, domains, IPs and MAC addresses, not hardware ids.

I've done extensive research in this area and use the the above two tools frequently. In my opinion they're much better and offer more protection than Zend Guard, for a significantly lower price point.